# Is there a good source for construction projects (CBS, WBS) written in Microsoft .mpp format?

Tags: industry

I am looking into automating the conversion of data written based on CBS (Cost breakdown structure) to data that are written based on WBS (Work breakdown structure). To do so, I needed a good number of CBS-WBS 1 to 1 pair dataset. However, I could not find any openly available data yet. Does anybody know where I can find such data? Or where can I start the search from?

Comment: what is .mpp format?

Comment: It is Microsoft Project format.

Comment: is that an open format?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by an open format. Do you mean that it is available for free use?

Comment: open formats: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_format  microsoft has a history of making proprietary formats. they've gotten better @ it recently, but their history remains.